# Batch file without error dialog

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, command

I need to create a batch file that run this command

```
start chrome
```

The problem is that I'm not sure that on the machine there is Google Chrome installed. I can't rely on the registry because I will not have admin permissions.

If I run this command on a machine where Chrome is not installed I get this error dialog

[image]

(you see "chromex". I used this name to simulate the absence of the software).

Is there a way to avoid to show this dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code snippet could help:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
SET "_chromePath="
If DEFINED programfiles(x86) (
  For /F "tokens=*" %%G in (
    'where /R "%programfiles(x86)%" chrome.exe  2^>NUL'
  ) do SET "_chromePath=%%G"
)
If NOT DEFINED _chromePath (
  For /F "tokens=*" %%G in (
    'where /R "%programfiles%" chrome.exe  2^>NUL'
  ) do SET "_chromePath=%%G"
)
If DEFINED _chromePath (
  echo start "" "%_chromePath%"
) else (
  echo chrome.exe not found
)
```

Note `start "" "%_chromePath%"` is `echo`ed merely for debugging purposes only.

**Resources** (required reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

@echo off

echo Enter 1 to start up Chrome

set /p input=Type here:

if %input%==1 goto chrome

:chrome

echo Starting chrome...

start chrome.exe

pause

Answer (score 0):

The dialog comes from using Start. Execute files directly to see the command prompt's equivlent.

```
'cat.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Normally one would open the web site and windows will use the user's choice of browser.

```
Start "" www.microsoft.com
start "" "c:\windows\help\mmc\htm\mmc_1.htm"
```

> I can't rely on the registry because I will not have admin permissions.

You have read access to most of the registry as a user and you can override most settings and file associations on a per user basis.